# Run python commands within the project directory without running into file does not exist error

Tags: python, path

Project structure:

```bash
├── main.py
└── utils
    ├── assets
    │   ├── export.csv
    ├── client.py
```

`utils/client.py` code snippet:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/assets/export.csv")
```

command within project root: `python utils/client.py`

```bash
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/assets/export.csv'
```

I want to make this code robust to avoid adding absolute path which will change from machine to machine.

Quesiton : How to import project root directory path in this place-holder in `utils/client.py` so that I can run the `command` mentioned above from anywhere within the project directory so that I don't run into this error.

```bash
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/assets/export.csv'
```

Something like this in `utils/client.py`

```py
from ../main.py import PROJECT_DIR_PATH
df = pd.read_csv(f"{PROEJECT_DIR_PATH}/utils/assets/export.csv")
```

and in `main.py`

```py
PROJECT_DIR_PATH = os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ´__file__´ attribute to access the path of your main module. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#file__

```
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: This solves the issue if I write this code in `utils/client.py` but what if I wanted this line of code in `main.py`. How would the importing look like in `client.py`?

Comment: How about `from ..main import PROJECT_PATH`

Comment: You could also use ’import sys
sys.path.append("..")’ to add the higher directory to python modules path.

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions. I found the first solution the best to my understanding.